# MySQL server 5.1 trigger problem

Tags: mysql, trigger, mysql-5.1

I have implemented a trigger. But once I try to update the table it is giving me the error:

> can't update table 'booking' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by the statement which invoked this stored function/trigger

This is the trigger

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER CANCEL_BOOK AFTER UPDATE on BOOKING
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
DELETE FROM BOOKING
    WHERE NEW.F_ID=NULL AND NEW.H_ID=NULL;
END //
DELIMITER ;
```

please help

Comment: The error message explains what is wrong. This restriction cannot be bypassed. So the way you select to solve your task is wrong. Publish/explain this task, maybe it can be solved without using a trigger.

Comment: An excellent example of an X-Y problem.

Comment: thank you @Akina but its is in my project to use a trigger and a saved procedure
hence i need to use the trigger or the saved procedure 
my project is about flights database reservation and cancellation 
i've created the database and the tables are login, registration, flights and booking 
i have already inserted the values to the database all i'm left to do is add a trigger and a short procedure so if you can help please guide me i need help before 4th december

Comment: thank you @mustaccio..... but i dont know much about what you are telling if you can explain it will be very helpful i am very keen on learning about such stuffs

Comment: *its is in my project to use a trigger and a saved procedure hence i need to use the trigger or the saved procedure* It is a training project?

Comment: Explain the logic that you need to implement, using human language. You seem to be using inappropriate tools for the job, but we don't know what your job is.

Comment: @Akina not a training project its for my exams  i am a 3rd year engineering student so its there for us that we have to do a miniproject using any front end and a database 
so i am using netbeans as the front end and mysql server 5.1 as the database

Comment: @mustaccio actually using netbeans i created some forms which will book and cancel the flights
f_id is flights id and h_id is hotels id
when a user wants to cancel the flights seat i remove the details of the flight seats of the current user and if the user wants to cancel the hotel room all the details related to hotel room of the user is removed from the table 
when this is done the row of the booking id is null except the booking id

Comment: so i want to delete the row as soon as a update operation is implemented which have f_id and h_id is null 
i can remove it using the netbeans only but since i am restricted to use one trigger and one stored procedure i thought of using it to delete the null rows

Comment: *i want to delete the row as soon as a update operation is implemented which have f_id and h_id is null* Possible. Using trigger. But not `DELETE` - it is restricted (see above). You must use `SIGNAL` producing error (in BEFORE INSERT, of course), it will break insertion.

Comment: @akina can you p please help me with the syntax??

Comment: Even after you figure out the problem in the question, you have another problem:  Test for `NULL` via `IS NULL`, _not_ `= NULL`.

Comment: I didn't get you @rickjames

Comment: @pksv - Notice how Akina's answer changed the syntax for the NULL test.

Answer (score 0):

Prevent record creation with F_ID and H_ID having NULL values (needs 5.5 or newer server version):

```
DELIMITER @@;

CREATE TRIGGER cancel_insert_book BEFORE INSERT ON booking
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF ((NEW.F_ID IS NULL) AND (NEW.H_ID IS NULL)) THEN
        SIGNAL SQLSTATE '23000'
        SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Both F_ID and H_ID cannot be NULL at the same time', 
        MYSQL_ERRNO = 1048;
    END IF;
END; 
@@;

CREATE TRIGGER cancel_update_book BEFORE UPDATE ON booking
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF ((NEW.F_ID IS NULL) AND (NEW.H_ID IS NULL)) THEN
        SIGNAL SQLSTATE '23000'
        SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'Both F_ID and H_ID cannot be NULL at the same time', 
        MYSQL_ERRNO = 1048;
    END IF;
END; 
@@;

DELIMITER ;
```

Remove record which have F_ID and H_ID having NULL values:

```
DELIMITER @@;

CREATE TRIGGER cancel_book AFTER UPDATE ON booking
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF ((NEW.F_ID IS NULL) AND (NEW.H_ID IS NULL)) THEN
        CREATE EVENT remove_record
        ON SCHEDULE AT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + INTERVAL 1 SECOND
        DO
          DELETE FROM booking
          WHERE ((f_id IS NULL) AND (h_id IS NULL));
    END IF;
END; 
@@;

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: thank you for you time and help but I want to remove that row if it is null I don't want it to show any error message. I mean that once those 2 values is null I no longer need that record in my database I want it to be deleted

Comment: *I want to remove that row* WHAT ROW? This trigger do not allow to create the record which have both field with NULL values - so there is no rows to remove.

Comment: this trigger won't allow me to set h_id and f_id as null but my question is that let's say if a person has booked both flight seat and hotel room so all the values in that row will be filled now suppose the person doesn't want to go so he starts cancelling the flight ticket and the room so once he does that the values for h_id and f_id will become null so I want a trigger that will delete such rows as soon as they become null

Comment: @Akina note also that MySQL Server 5.1 does not support `SIGNAL`.  This was not introduced until 5.5.

Comment: @pksv *I want a trigger that will delete such rows as soon as they become null* Updated.

Comment: hey @Akina i tried the code given by you but it gave this error
ERROR 1576 (HY000): Recursion of EVENT DDL statements is forbidden when body is present
please help

Comment: If so do NOT use trigger at all, but create a periodical (with 1-2 second period, for example) event which delete all those 2-NULL records unconditionally. And create proper index for this delete optimization.

Comment: well in my project it is compulsory to use atleast one trigger and one stored procedure 
so i used the trigger to call the procedure which contained
IF ((NEW.F_ID IS NULL) AND (NEW.H_ID IS NULL)) THEN
        CREATE EVENT remove_record
        ON SCHEDULE AT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + INTERVAL 1 SECOND
        DO
          DELETE FROM booking
          WHERE ((f_id IS NULL) AND (h_id IS NULL));
    END IF;
and then this error showed up and i copied the same code you gave that is the for the trigger but the same error showed up so please help

Comment: Look the documentation for SP and trigger restrictions... maybe events cannot be created in a trigger at all? If it is educational project I'd recommend to use SP for record updating instead of simple UPDATE query, and to look for another point for trigger applying (for example, while updating some second table while altering data... re-calculate current customer balance value in customer table by payment registration in payments table).

Comment: OK I'll try @akina